# Validating connection from csv file and ssh into multiple servers

Tags: bash, networking

Hey everyone I am trying to create a script that validates connection across servers, So far I am able to ssh into the first connection but not the rest of them. The problem is that this script is only reading first line and using that to ssh. How do I make the script read the entire file?

```
while read -r line
do
    sourceip=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{printf "%s", $1}' | tr -d '"')
    destip=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{printf "%s", $2}' | tr -d '"')
    port=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{printf "%s", $3}' | tr -d '"')
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes root@$sourceip "nc -zv $destip  $port;exit" && echo "Done" || echo ERR
done < servers.csv
```

Comment: Run your script with '-x' to find out where does it hangs ? It is possible that it's waiting on the 'ssh' or 'nc zv ...' command ?

Comment: its not hanging, its able to successfully ssh and exit for 1st connection but then script just stops

Comment: What it the content of server.csv first few lines ? maybe something wrong with second line, causing the read to fail.

Comment: 10.0.0.0,10.0.0.1,443
10.0.0.0,10.0.0.2,80

I cant expose the real ips so these are just a example

Comment: figured it out. Im using a while loop. Need to use for loop :)

Comment: @Nabmeister Not quite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `ssh` process reads from stdin, consuming the rest of your input to read in the while loop. You can work around this issue in two ways. The first is to use the `-n` argument to `ssh`, which redirects stdin from `/dev/null`. The other option is to manually redirect by adding `< /dev/null` to the end of your `ssh` command.